# Is there a way to automatically specify the default branch when calling the Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to fetch all the pull requests from the Github API that had their base as a repo's default branch, using the following code:

```py
pr_generator = gh.getiter(
        "/repos/{organisation}/{repo}/pulls?state={state}&sort={sort}&base={base}&direction={direction}",
        url_vars={
            "sort": "updated",
            "base": "master",
            "state": "all",
            "organisation": requester,
            "repo": repo,
            "direction": "desc",
        },
    )
```

This is fine as long as the default branch is called 'master', which is increasingly not the case. Is there a way to specify 'default' and for the default branch to be used, whatever its name is. Or any way that is more efficient than calling `/repos/{owner}/{repo}` to fetch the `default_branch`.

Comment: Have you tried `HEAD`?

Comment: I haven't. Could you specify what you mean?

Comment: Instead of writing `master` for the base, try `HEAD`.  GitHub points the `HEAD` symbolic reference to the default branch, and that might work for your case (although I haven't tested).